# How can I bind Racket's multiple return values to global variable names using define?

Tags: lisp, racket, multiple-return-values

Given a simple function that returns one value, I can use `define` to bind its return value to a name

```
(define (foo) 1)
(define bar (foo))
```

however this doesn't seem to be possible when the function returns multiple values using `values`.

```
(define (baz) (values 2 3))
(define quux (baz))
  ; define-values: result arity mismatch;
  ;  expected number of values not received
  ;   expected: 1
  ;   received: 2
  ;   from: 
  ;   in: definition of quux
  ;   values...:
  ;    2
  ;    3
```

I've looked through the docs, but the only thing related to `values` is `let-values`, which doesn't really apply here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [`define-values`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define.html#%28form._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._define-values%29%29), the definition equivalent to `let-values`.

```
(define (baz) (values 2 3))
(define-values (foo bar) (baz))
```